# rearranging equation for derivative with a fraction

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have something in the form of $$\frac{a}{bx^c}$$

I know when you have just a square root in the bottom you pull down the a to be a coefficient for x, and multiply it by c and raise x to the power of c-1. What do you do when x already has a coefficient, b? just a/b times x then a/b times c and x tot he power of c-1?

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: You would be right, if $x^c$ would be in the numerator. It is a good idea to write $x^c$ in the numerator by adding a negative sign to c: $\frac{a}{b}x^{-c}$. But you are right, that the fraction remains the same factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{a}{bx^c}=\frac{a}{b}x^{-c}$$

Now simply differentiate using the power law to get

$$f'(x)=\frac{a}{b}(-c)x^{-c-1}$$